# Why Dispatch doesnt work and crash the app

Tags: redux

So basically i have reducer with state called isHamburgerIsOpen. This is for to check if hamburger icon is clicked i want to blur my background:

```html
import React, {useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ThemeProvider } from 'styled-components';
import theme from '../Themes/Themes';
import Background from '../styledComponents/Background';
import LeftMainInfo from '../components/Main/Left/LeftMainInfo';
import RightMainInfo from '../components/Main/Right/RightMainInfo';
import FlexWrapper from '../styledComponents/FlexWrapper';
import MenuSide from '../components/Main/Menu/MenuSide';

const Main = () => {
    const isHamburgerIsOpen = useSelector(({appStatesReducer})=> appStatesReducer.main.isHamburgerIsOpen);
    const blur = () => {
      if(isHamburgerIsOpen === true){
        return 'blur(20px)'
      }
      else{
        return null
      }
    }
    const history = useHistory();
    const [cookies] = useCookies();
    const [isAuth, setIsAuth] = useState(false);
    useEffect(() => {
        const checkAuth = async () => {
            try{
                const res = await fetch('http://localhost:5000/checkAuth', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: JSON.stringify({ jwt: cookies.jwt }),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
            })
                const data = await res.json();
                if(data.isAuth === true){
                    setIsAuth(true)
                }
                else{
                    history.push("/");
                }
            }
            catch(err) {
                console.log(err)
            }
        }
        checkAuth();
      },);
      
      // start coding
      if(isAuth === false) return <h1>Loading...</h1>
      if(isAuth === true) return (
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Background blur={blur}  bgPosition='center' url={process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/night.jpg'} position='relative'>
            <FlexWrapper direction='row' justify='space-between' align='flex-start' padding='70px 150px 0px 60px'>
              <LeftMainInfo />
              <RightMainInfo />
            </FlexWrapper>
           <MenuSide />
          </Background>
        </ThemeProvider>
      )
}


export default Main;
```

In here i download a status of that state from redux then i am checking status and set the background blur

```html
import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import {CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN} from '../../../actions/index';
import BarSearchWidget from '../Left/BarSearchWidget';
import SideBar from '../SideBar/SideBar';
import gsap from 'gsap';
const MenuSide = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const wrapper = useRef(null);
    const [isLoupeOpen, setIsLoupeOpen] = useState(false);
    const [isHamburgerOpen, setIsHamburgerOpen] = useState(false);
    const showLoupe = () => {
        const [elements] = wrapper.current.children;

        const searchForm = elements.getElementsByClassName("search");
        const loupe = elements.getElementsByClassName("loupe");

        gsap.set(searchForm, { transformOrigin: "0% 100%" });

        const t1 = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: "power3.inOut" } });

        if(!isLoupeOpen){
            t1.fromTo(searchForm, { scaleX: 0 }, { duration: 1, autoAlpha: 1, scaleX: 1 });
            t1.fromTo(loupe, {x: '-=0'}, {duration: 1, x: '+=265'})
            setIsLoupeOpen(!isLoupeOpen)
        }
        else{
            t1.fromTo(loupe, {x: '+=0'}, {x: '-=265', duration: 1})
            t1.fromTo(searchForm, { scaleX: 1 }, {duration: 1, autoAlpha: 0, scaleX: 0 });
            setIsLoupeOpen(!isLoupeOpen)
        }
    }
    const sayHello = () => {
        
        const [elements] = wrapper.current.children;
        const sidebar = elements.getElementsByClassName("sidebar");

        gsap.set(sidebar, { transformOrigin: "50% 100%" });

        const t1 = gsap.timeline({ defaults: { ease: "power3.inOut" } });

        if(!isHamburgerOpen){
            dispatch(CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN())
            t1.fromTo(sidebar, { scaleY: 0 }, { duration: 1, autoAlpha: 1, scaleY: 1 });
            setIsHamburgerOpen(!isHamburgerOpen)

        }else{

        }
    }
    return (
        <div ref={wrapper}>
            <div>
                <BarSearchWidget showLoupe={showLoupe} sayHello={sayHello}/>
                <SideBar />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MenuSide
```

Here i animate my things, but in sayHello function after click i want to dispatch to change state status but i am getting error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWvuS.png)

Also my redux and action:

```html
let appStates = {
    main: {
        isHamburgerIsOpen: false
    }
}

const appStatesReducer = (state = appStates, action) => {
    switch(action.type){
           case 'CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN':
               return !state
            default:
                return state;
    }
}

export default appStatesReducer;
```

```html
export const REQUEST_SUCCESS = (n) => {
    return {
        type: 'REQUEST_SUCCESS',
        payload: n
    }
}
export const CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN = () => {
    return {
        type: 'CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say there's a problem with your reducer. Let's take a closer a look at it:

```js
const appStatesReducer = (state = appStates, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN':
      return !state
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

What you want to do in response to the `CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN` is to change the value of the `isHamburgerIsOpen` flag, only that. In this piece of code, however, **what you're actually doing is override the whole state by a boolean value**.

When you call the action for the first time, since state has an initial value, `!state` is evaluated to `false`. **This means that your state will now be set to `false`, and the whole structure you defined in `appStates` will no longer exists.**

This is the reason behind the `Cannot read property 'isHamburgerIsOpen' of undefined` you're getting, probably when this line is run:

```js
const isHamburgerIsOpen = useSelector(
  ({ appStatesReducer }) => appStatesReducer.main.isHamburgerIsOpen
);
```

Since `appStatesReducer` has now a value of `false`, it has no property called `main` nor `isHamburgerIsOpen`. This is what causes the exception to appear.

In order to solve this, **you need to fix your reducer so only the `isHamburgerIsOpen` property of the current state is updated**.

```js
const appStatesReducer = (state = appStates, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'CHANGE_ISHAMBURGERISOPEN':
      return {
        ...state,
        main: {
          ...state.main,
          isHamburgerIsOpen: !state.main.isHamburgerIsOpen,
        },
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

When modifying your reducer you need to make sure that the structure of the initial state is always preserved, or this kind of error may happen again.